# mysql Rank with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, rank

Here is my code to get the rank from the table, but I want to connect two more tables with INNER JOIN, but when I use the INNER JOIN the Rank will change.. Please help me to solve this issue...

```
SELECT ex_studentid, ex_studentname, ex_subjid, ex_batchno, ex_examdate, 
ex_code, ex_marks, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM cp_exams p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY  ex_marks DESC;
```

Code with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT ex_studentid, ex_studentname, ex_subjid, ex_batchno, ex_examdate, ex_code,
ex_marks, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM cp_exams p INNER JOIN `cp_students` 
ON stu_studentID = ex_studentid, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY  ex_marks DESC;
```

-------------------My Mysql Tables-----------------

```
CREATE TABLE `cp_exams` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ex_studentid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ex_studentname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ex_subjid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ex_batchno` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ex_examdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ex_code` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ex_marks` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=29
```

I want to connect these tables with cp_exams and get the student ranks for ex_marks.....

```
CREATE TABLE `cp_students` (
    `stu_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `stu_studentID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `stu_regdate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `stu_studentname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `stu_address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_sex` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `stu_bday` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_con_home` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_con_mobile1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_con_mobile2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_notes` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'big5_chinese_ci',
    `stu_passGrade` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_image_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_nic` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_school` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stu_accesskey` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`stu_ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=800
;


CREATE TABLE `cp_exams_list` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ex_code` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ex_des` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

Comment: We need to see some actual data in order to answer .

Comment: Here is the tables....

Comment: With `INNER JOIN`, is there the same result between your two queries except column `rank`?